# Какая сложность у этого блока кода?

Tags: сложность

Не могу понять, почему тут сложность O(n^2)?

```
for(i = 0;i<n;i++){
    for(j = 0;j<i;j++){
      sequence of statements
    }
}
```

Comment: А ты как думаешь - какая тут сложность и почему именно так?

Comment: а сколько раз ты проходишь по sequence of statements?

Comment: Ну к примеру, в sequence of statements будет print("Hello world!");

Comment: https://trinket.io/python3/116ff7b89e?runMode=console наглядно количество итераций от N

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Считается, что у такого кода сложность O(*n*<sup>2</sup>).

Внутренний цикл на каждой итерации внешнего цикла выполняется сначала 0, потом 1, 2 и так далее до *n*−2 раз, пока выполняются условия *j*<*i*<*n*.

Общее количество выполнений внутреннего цикла равно 0 + 1 + 2 + ... + *n*−2. Это сумма членов арифметической прогрессии, которая считается по формуле *S* = (*a*<sub>1</sub>+*a*<sub>m</sub>)×*m*/2, где *m* — общее количество элементов.

В вашем случае *a*<sub>1</sub> = 0, *a*<sub>m</sub> = *n*−2, *m* = *n*−1.

Итого, *S* = (*n*−1)(*n*−2)/2 = (*n*<sup>2</sup>-3*n*+2)/2.

В нотации О-большое мы оцениваем производительность алгоритмов на высоком уровне, не детальном. Поэтому отбрасываем все несущественные части суммы.

При больших значениях *n*, *n*<sup>2</sup> несоизмеримо больше, чем просто *n*, и большее чем константа 2, поэтому от (*n*<sup>2</sup>-3*n*+2)/2 остаётся *n*<sup>2</sup>/2.

Точно также мы отбрасываем константные множители, у нас это 1/2. Таким образом, *n*<sup>2</sup>/2 превращается в *n*<sup>2</sup>.

Поэтому сложность O(*n*<sup>2</sup>).

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае сложность действительно квадратичная О(n^2).

Строго говоря, количество итераций здесь:

0 + 1 + … + n-1 = n * (0 + n - 1) / 2 = (n^2 - n)/2

Это по формуле арифметической прогрессии.

Конечно это не ровно n^2, а слегка меньше. Но О-большое это верхняя граница, а не точная оценка. Под линейную или, скажем, логарифмическую сложности приведенный вами алгоритм явно не подходит.